# Zeros of Jacobi elliptic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

For the past month or so, I have been studying Jacobi elliptic functions $sn$, $cn$ and $dn$. However I stumbled upon a problem and it goes as following:

I am trying to find $z \in \mathbb{C}$, such that $sn(z) = sin({\psi}) = 0$, where $\psi$ is the inverse of the integral:
$$z(\psi) = \int_0 ^\psi \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2(x)}} dx .$$

By definig constant $K$ as:

$$K = K(k) = \int_0 ^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2(z)}} dz $$ I was able to prove by induction that:
$$2K = \int_{\pi(k-1)}^{\pi k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2(z)}} dz $$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ To find zeros of $sn$ I did the following:
$$sn(z) = \sin(\psi) = 0 \iff \psi = n\pi \iff z = \int_0 ^{n\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2(z)}} dz $$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I rewrote the last integral as:
$$z = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\pi(k-1)}^{\pi k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2(z)}}dz = \sum_{k=1}^n 2K = 2nK.$$
Now it appears as is I found all zeros of $sn(z)$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$, however there are also zeros of the form $2iK’$, where $K’$ is:
$$ K’ = K(k’) = 2K = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k’^2 \sin^2(z)}} dz $$ where $k’ = \sqrt{1 - k^2}.$ Now I obviously made mistake somewhere however I have no idea where. I would appreciate any help or tips.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Jacobi's Imaginary Transformation.
It is
$$\sin\varphi=i\tan\psi$$ under this,

$$\int\frac{d\varphi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\varphi}}=
i\int\frac{d\psi}{\sqrt{1-k^{\prime 2}\sin^2\psi}}$$

This allows you to prove that the periods of $sn(z)$ are $2K$ and $4K^{\prime}i$. Modulo these periods you have all the roots.

Comment: I am familiar whit this method, however at the moment I am more interested in why did I not get all solutions from my calculation above.

Comment: Basically there are multiple complex paths fro $0$ to $\pi$. You have only taken the real path. The other paths give the zeros plus the periods.

Comment: That makes sense, so if I took a line path from $0$ to $^i\pi$ and then circular path from $i \pi$ to $\pi$ that would(possibly) give me my missing zeros? Oh and in your answer the period of $sn$ should be $4K$.